# How to use Google APIs without continuously explicit user consent from a progressive web application?

Tags: google-oauth

I have a progressive web application that needs write-access to the Google Drive API for uploading data (media files) the user is creating (either online or offline) in the background while online. It does not really need a server (except for serving the required files, so a static server is sufficient), all of the work could be done on the web application client side.

Since uploading needs to happen on the background, whenever the user is online again (using a service worker and the background sync one-shot API), an access token is not enough for my need (the user can be offline/not use the web application for days) and a refresh token is not supposed to be stored on the web application client side, as far as I understand. Even if it were, I would still need the client secret, which means I have to use a server (or keep the secret within the web application client side, which is a no-no) in order to refresh the token.

It seems like the current ways of using the OAuth2 scheme are at odds with server-less progressive web applications, or I might be missing something. Progressive web applications are more like Chrome applications in this regard, I guess, but I have to supply a Chrome application ID in the Google API console for my application, which I do not (and do not intend to) have and Chrome applications use the Chrome identity API for getting the tokens, which I do not intend to use (and cannot).

I am currently using an actual Node.js server which takes care of the authorization step, keeps the access token and refresh token in a database and returns the existing or new access token to the client, whenever asked. The server is redundant here (and requires a privacy policy for this data which I really do not need to store), I want to do everything using client code, without continuously asking for authorization whenever I upload in the background.

Keeping the refresh token on the web application client side and just reaching out to the server for actually refreshing the access token (nothing must be stored in the server side except the client secret, which is fine), but like I mentioned, I understand the refresh token is not supposed to be kept on the web application side.

Is there a safe and secure way to implement this without a server (or with a server that only gets the refresh token and returns it to the client and refreshes the access token by getting the refresh token from the client)?

Comment: If you want to do this client side then your only option is the access token  and asking the user for permissions again when they logon.    Only server side languages can request a refresh token.

Comment: @DaImTo - I imagine so. I mainly posted this to get the attention of Google regarding the matter, perhaps they have a change of policy in the works.

(I would have done so in a discussion group, but I read that it has been moved to StackOverflow with this tag)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually fairly simple, depending on the fine details of your use case.

An important factoid is that once a user has granted permission to your app, he will not have to re-grant it. So you don't need to "continuously asking for authorization whenever I upload in the background". However, the only constraint is that the user must be logged in to Google in order to obtain an Access Token. Normally this isn't an issue, but your app needs to deal with the scenario that a user has logged off from Google, and prompt for login.

All the details are here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

I suggest avoid the Google JS library because (a) it has its own opinions about the UX, (b) wasn't written with PWAs in mind, (c) has issues on mobile, and (d) is closed  source so when it breaks (as it does occasionally), your users are dead in the water until Google fixes it. The page above details the OAuth endpoints so you can easily use them directly. This has the side benefit that adding other cloud storage accounts (AWS, Azure, Drop, etc) is just a case of changing the endpoint URL.

The architecture I use in my PWA is to have my PWA prompt once (and once only) for authorization and then store the user's Gmail address in localStorage. I then have a 
hidden iframe which polls once per hour for an Access Token, using the gmail address in a `login_hint`. This means the iframe is never required to present any UX. The only time UX is required is for the initial auth, which is of course unavoidable, and once per session if the user has logged out of Google.

The only other edge-case you  might want to deal  with is allowing the user to select between multiple Google accounts, say a personal  account and a work domain account.

On a broader point, remember that Google didn't create the OAuth spec so there is little they can do to provide an alternative solution. At an abstract level, auth requires one of the user being present, or secure storage for a permanent token (eg on a server or within a secure store such as Android). Even if we invent OAuth 3, that will still be the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perhaps I should have elaborated a bit more about my use case. I have a progressive web application that is basically a mobile voice recorder. That means it is inactive most of the time (so no iFrame to keep my access token fresh) and since uploading is done by a service worker once online (my phone is offline most of the time, for example), it means I cannot use an iFrame there as well (service workers do not support iFrames). Side note - I already use `fetch` and not the Google JavaScript library (even though they highly discourage this for security reasons).

Comment: Huh, using `fetch("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?...", {mode: "no-cors", credentials: "include"})` (with `login_hint`) instead of using an iFrame seems to also work in the simple case (the user is logged into Google)! That might just solve it without much hassle. I will try that and update.

Comment: the iframe is not needed behind a service worker since it is only relevant when your app is online. `fetch` might have been a bum-steer in that I use the URL as the iframe src. If `fetch` actually works, that makes things even easier.