# Redirect_uri mismatch in fetch and gapi

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-js-client

working on connecting users to google, and we're trying to get their access and refresh tokens from the google api, and we're getting an issue exchanging the OAuth2 Code for tokens. Both sets of code have the same error.

I initialize the gapi client and fill in the information needed like so:

```
gapi.load('client:auth2', _ => {
        gapi.client.init({
            'apiKey': 'omitted for security',
            clientId: 'omitted for security',
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest']    
        }).then(_ => {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess().then(resp => {
                if(resp.code){
                    gapi.client.request({
                        path: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
                        method: 'post',
                        params: {code: resp.code},
                        body: {
                            code: resp.code,
                            client_id: opts.clientId,
                            client_secret: 'omitted for security',
                            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                            redirect_uri: 'omitted for security',
                            access_type: 'offline'
                        },
                    }).then((onfulfill, onreject, context) => {
                        console.log('fulfilled', onfulfill);
                        console.log('rejected: ', onreject);
                        console.log('context', context);
                    }).catch(err => console.error(err.body));
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

What I'm trying to do in the `.then()` is to call the token endpoint to exchange the code in the response for a refresh and access token to store in my back end and the user's local storage.

I get this error response from both versions of the code. (better, more reliable code is provided here.)

> {   "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",   "error_description": "Bad
>   Request" }

I also have a backend setup stashed as a last resort that accepts the code from `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess()` calls the token endpoint, and returns the `access_token` and `refresh_token` to the client.

This code is similar, but not quite. instead of using the google api library, I used fetch, and it works fine. (Fetch and XHR on the front end have the same issues as the `gapi.client.request` function....)

```
const gConfig = require('./basic.json');
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

const { client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris } = gConfig.web;
const authClient = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { code } = req.body;
    console.log('Received Code From Request: ', code);

    let data = { code , client_id, client_secret,redirect_uri: redirect_uris[0], grant_type: 'refresh_token'};

    let encodedParams = Object.keys(data).map(k => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k])).join('&');


    fetch(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?code=${code}`,
        { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, body: encodedParams }
    ).then((res) => {
        console.log('called the api with fetch');
        console.dir(res.json());
    });

    authClient.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        // console.dir(token);
        console.log('TOKEN: =>', token);
        res.json(token);
    });
});
```

Is there anyone that's done this on the front end successfully?

Comment: SO preserves previous versions of your question, so your secrets are still visible. You need to login to the API console and delete those credentials.

Comment: they're not used in production (or active development) anyway, so I can easily remove them. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a refresh token in a browser. Your example code would only work on a server. To do oauth at the client you should request "token" instead of "code".

Comment: Are you saying that my `grant_type` should be 'authorization_token' instead of 'authorization_code'? also is it in the docs anywhere that the refresh token is denied to the browser?

Comment: I see that, but does it explain that there will never be a refresh token on the front end?

Comment: I think the specs and docs only explain what you can do. A list of things that you cannot do would be quite long. You might find something in the OAuth specs. The reason OAuth issues an Auth Code, rather than a Refresh Token directly is specifically to keep RTs away from the client,and to prevent the client knowing any secrets. By embedding a client_secret in your code, it's not really a secret anymore.

Comment: My answer here might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960067/how-to-use-google-apis-without-continuously-explicit-user-consent-from-a-progres/53969255#53969255. 

In the absence of a RT in a browser client, you basically need to keep doing an Auth to fetch an Access Token, but use `prompt=none` on the second and subsequent request so the process happens in the background in a hidden iframe.